# wpf, register DP, bindable converter parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, valueconverter

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(object), typeof(object))]
public class BindableConvertor : DependencyObject, IValueConverter
{
    public object BindableParameter
    {
        get { return GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(BindableParameter),
            typeof(object),
            typeof(BindableConvertor),
            new PropertyMetadata(String.Empty)
            );


    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // actions here...
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <local:BindableConvertor x:Key="MyConvertor" BindableParameter="{Binding AnyTargetProperty}" />
</Application.Resources>
```

Finally:

```
<ListBox Name="ViewBox"
                     Grid.Row="0"
                     DisplayMemberPath="Value"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding SomePropertyFromWindowDataContext,
                                           Converter={StaticResource MyConvertor}}" />
```

Result: 
System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=; DataItem=null; target element is 'BindableConvertor' (HashCode=19986012); target property is 'BindableParameter' (type 'Object'). 
And my "BindableParameter" always equals to default value (null).

But if I do something like:

```
        <local:BindableConvertor x:Key="MyConvertor" BindableParameter="Constant text here..." />
```

... then it works perfectly.

Any ideas why?

Comment: There may be no DataContext set when the converter is instantiated in the Application's Resources, hence there is no source object for the `AnyTargetProperty` binding. Put it in the MainWindow's Resources, or whereever you are using it. Alternatively, don't make it a resource, but instantiate it in-place when you set the ItemsSource binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably because your converter inherits from DependencyObject. Try Freezable instead.

Comment: Thx a lot! That was the solution. But can u give some explanations how does 'Freezable' work or just ref appropriate blog?..